# Would it be appropriate for me to ask the question in the body?

Tags: discussion

The question is:

"Where could I find where the different drugs lie, pregnancy category wise, in Australia?"

I want to ask this question because it is driving me mad trying to find a document detailing said pregnancy categories and I'm desperate and this stackexchange website seems the most appropriate for this question.

Comment: I would suggest asking what the Australian Institute of Health (or whatever) categorizes stages of pregnancy as, and make clear you want links to the source documentation in the body of your question.

Comment: Try quora. Seems much more suitable for this class of question.